# Editable area in Textfields in ExtJs5

Tags: extjs, textfield, extjs5

Textfields are not working in ExtJs 5. This is my definition :

```
       {
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            name: 'firstName',
            width : 200,
            allowBlank: false
        }
```

The label comes on top of editable area and  editable area comes much smaller then the total width. It worked fine in Ext 4.

Comment: Try to reproduce issue on fiddle. With this code only it would be quite hard to answer.

Answer (score 2):

To position the label inside the [Ext.form.field.Text](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text) component you can use [labelAlign](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-labelAlign) property and you can set the width of label inside the component using [labelWidth](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-labelWidth) property also from [Ext.form.Labelable](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable) mixin.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
    fieldLabel: 'First Name',
    padding: 10,
    name: 'firstName',
    allowBlank: false,

    width : 400, //width of component
    labelAlign: 'right', //position of label
    labelWidth: 200, // width of label

    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

### Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqoaeLjt/)